# Rename require ngModel in Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I have developed some directives and in them I use a certain pattern for naming attributes. All of the attributes are prefixed with "fs-" for example `<div fs-attrtibute="value"></div>`

Is it possible to use a custom name for the ngModel attribute and still retain the model controller functionality. For example `<div fs-model="value" fsDirective></div>`

```
myApp.directive('fsDirective', function() {
    return {
        require: 'fsModel',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue('StackOverflow');          
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've presented it here Angular would look for a controller on a directive named 'fsModel' and supply that to your link function's 'ngModel' argument. It might be possible to wrap ngModel in a custom 'pass-thru' directive, but that would introduce complexity for very small benefit.

We similarly use a 'namespace' for all of our local directives, but leave Angular's 'ng' space alone because it's clear and consistent.